# Opening a ContextMenu from a button click

Tags: wpf, button, click, contextmenu

I'm trying to create a button that displays content in a popup when it is clicked. So I came up with something simple like this :

```
public class DropdownButton : Button
{
    public object DropdownContent
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DropdownContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DropdownContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DropdownContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DropdownContent", typeof(object), typeof(DropdownButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        base.OnClick();

        if(DropdownContent != null)
        {
            if(DropdownContent is ContextMenu)
            {
                ContextMenu = (ContextMenu)DropdownContent;
                ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // launch a popup
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and am using it like this :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public string A { get { return "A"; } }
    public string B { get { return "B"; } }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication45.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfApplication45"
    Title="MainWindow"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="sharedMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="{Binding}" />
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <UniformGrid Columns="2"
                 DataContext="{Binding A}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                   Background="#CCC"
                   ContextMenu="{StaticResource sharedMenu}"/>
        <l:DropdownButton DropdownContent="{StaticResource sharedMenu}" />
    </UniformGrid>

    <UniformGrid Columns="2"
                 DataContext="{Binding B}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                   Background="#CCC"
                   ContextMenu="{StaticResource sharedMenu}"/>
        <l:DropdownButton DropdownContent="{StaticResource sharedMenu}" />
    </UniformGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

But it isn't behaving as expected. If you try clicking a button, the ContextMenu pops up but without having it's DataContext set.

If I manually set the DataContext like this :

```
ContextMenu = (ContextMenu)DropdownContent;
                ContextMenu.DataContext = DataContext;
                ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
```

it breaks the binding on the TextBlocks ContextMenu

Answer (score 0):

To be perfectly honest, I don't know why this works, but if I apply the following change :

```
 protected override void OnClick()
    {
        base.OnClick();

        if (DropdownContent != null)
        {
            if (DropdownContent is ContextMenu)
            {
                ContextMenu = (ContextMenu)DropdownContent;
                ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = this;
                ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // launch a popup
            }
        }
    }
```

As well as disable Menu animations :

```
  <Application.Resources>
    <PopupAnimation x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}">None</PopupAnimation>
</Application.Resources>
```

Things work ...